# New directory or file is not getting created on running the scraper (scrapy) through cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

[this is the main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgA0h.png)

[this is the settings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBEph.png)

[pipelines.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKE9U.png)

[items.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etx4J.png)

Whenever I run the scraper, it is supposed to create a json file. The scraper works fine, but it just doesn't save the contents to the file.

Comment: Hi! Please post your code as text instead of images - it's much easier for us to suggest changes when we can edit snippets of your code without having to transcribe it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `FEED_URI` like below in settings.py

```
FEED_URI = 'file:///E:/python/venv/demo/temp/%(Name)s-%(time)s.json'
```

`%(Name)s` will be replaced by the name of the spider and `%(time)s` will be replaced by the time when the crawler was run thus creating a new file every time.